# Deploying Express on Bluehost

Tags: reactjs, express, bluehost

Sorry for the ignorance here -- new to the game. I am attempting to deploy a PERN app to Bluehost. I'm using react-router to serve static pages on the front end, this is working fine. To get this to work, I had to edit the .htaccess as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am attempting access a pg database on the front end by serving via Express. I've downloaded Node to the server via SSH and know I am able to access my 'users' database by just logging to the command line. My simple router looks as such:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const pool = new Pool({
    user: "proofrm4_admin",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "proofrm4_main",
    password: "******",
  });

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const users = await Pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
      return res.status(200).json({data: users.rows});
  } catch(err) {
      return res.status(400).json({error: err});
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

My front end fetch request is as such:

```
import NavBar from '../components/Navbar';

const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
      const users = await fetch('http://localhost/users', {
          method: 'GET'
      });
      return await users.json();
  } catch(err) {
      return {err};
  }
};

const users = await getUsers();

const HomePage = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
        <NavBar/>
        {console.log(users)}
    </div>
  )
}
  

export default HomePage;
```

I've tried all sorts of cors settings and have also played with adding a proxy at localhost:3000 to the package.json file. Despite this, I can't get the Express server to properly serve the database information. Is there something else I need to add to the .htaccess? Do I need a different proxy? Is there just an easier way to go about this completely? Thanks in advance for the help!